# how to plot lots of data in a graph with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to display 100 values in a single bar chart, but the labels and corresponding values overlap.

as follows

[image]

the code is as follows:

```
  plt.bar(range(len(freq_to_plot)), [val[1] for val in freq_to_plot], align='center')
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    title = ax.set_title("\n".join(wrap(name_file, 60)))
    fig.tight_layout()
    title.set_y(1.05)
    fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)
    plt.xticks(range(len(freq_to_plot)), [val[0] for val in freq_to_plot])
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.tight_layout()
    labels, values = split_freq(freq_to_plot)
    plt.bar(labels, values, color='blue')
    for i in range(len(values)):
        plt.annotate(str(values[i]), xy=(labels[i], values[i]), ha='center', va='bottom')
    plt.savefig("figures/" + name_file + ".png", bbox_inches="tight")
    plt.show()
```

how can I fix it?

thanks

Comment: TBH 100 bars is a little too many. On the other note, horizontal bars with `barh` might look better.

Comment: if you HAVE to use that layout, then increase `figsize` to something like `plt.figure(figsize=(20,4)`

Comment: Yeah, either do what @Yuca said and / or (1) think about changing font sizes (2) remove the bar annotations, as they should not be needed anyway (that's what you have yticks for!).